# Flake fails on update, nimPackages is missing, where has it gone?

Tags: nix, nim-lang, nixpkgs

A while back, I had a flake.nix which worked:

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
      in {
        packages = rec {
          hello = pkgs.nim2Packages.buildNimPackage {
            pname = "hello";
            version = "0.1.0";
            src = ./hello;
          };

          default = hello;
        };
      });

}
```

After running `nix flake update` it stopped working with this error message:

```
error: attribute 'nimPackages' missing

       at /nix/store/rkp543s3nhhichwg03kffd515411mikm-source/test/samples/greeter/flake.nix:12:19:

           11|         packages = rec {
           12|           hello = pkgs.nimPackages.buildNimPackage {
             |                   ^
           13|             pname = "hello";
       Did you mean elmPackages?
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a git bisect and tracked it down to [this nixpkgs PR](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/268685)

Two changes, the first is just a rename/reorg:
`pkgs.nim2Packages.buildNimPackage` -> `pkgs.buildNimPackage`

The other required that I generate a lockfile:

```
❯ nix-shell -p nim_lk
$ nim_lk ./hello > ./hello/lock.json
$ exit
❯ git add ./hello/lock.json
```

Then I needed to reference the lockfile in the call to `buildNimPackage`.  Here's the `flake.nix` after making the changes:

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
      in {
        packages = rec {
          hello = pkgs.buildNimPackage {
            pname = "hello";
            version = "0.1.0";
            src = ./hello;
            lockFile = ./hello/lock.json;
          };
          default = hello;
        };
      });
}
```

Comment: How did you `git bisect` on a flake dependency? Is there a command similar to `nix flake update` to do this or did you clone nixpkgs locally and somehow pointed your flake to local copy that you `git bisect` then?

Comment: It was a little bit arduous.  I cloned nixpkgs and started the bisect with `git bisect bad` then checked out ref from the `flake.lock` which worked and did `git bisect good`.  Then I let git handle the bisecting and each time I copied the ref it from each step into the flake input:  `nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs?ref=bisect-hash-goes-here";`.  Then I ran `nix build` to see if it was good or bad, and I then ran `git bisect good` or `git bisect bad` over in the nixpkgs repo.  It took about 15 steps to find the culprit.  Automatic bisecting of inputs would be a super cool feature.

Comment: In retrospect, your idea is better. I should've just pointed the input at my local nixpkgs.